# Make PdfLatex in Winedt as fast as PdfLatex in TeXStudio

Tags: pdftex, texstudio, winedt

While I prefer WinEdt much more than TeXStudio, but I am surprised how fast TeXStudio can execute PdfLaTex. I tried in WinEdt to make it as similar as possible to how TeXStudio handles the log and output that is so fast, but still it is not close to TeXStudio. Here is how I set Winedt:

[image]

and here is the the TeXstudio command:

```
txs:///compile | txs:///view
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Deselect "Open Error Dialog" and "Redirect Console I/O". Also, why are you not using the console?

Comment: sorry for the delay! I was on the flight! If I do as you said, the result would be slightly slower! Also the Winedt console will be open always, but if I do as I mentioned above, the winedt console will be visible only if there is any error and it will be disappeared automatic ally after resolving the issue. Is there any way to choose Winedt console as you mentioned, but make it auto-hide if there is no error? ans also faster as it is in TeXStudio. I cam make two videos to show the slight different between these two editors if that helps!

Comment: I don't know what the difference can be caused by, but surely to mimic TeXStudio behavior, you have to check "No Interaction"

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't make any different in terms of speed!